# How can I find fifth root of unity?

Tags: proof-verification, roots-of-unity, trigonometric-series

I have no idea to do this question, how can I find the fifth root of unity?

*Question* :

Find all the distinct fifth root of unity. Let $\alpha$ be a fifth root of unity such that $\alpha \ne 1$.

Prove that $1 + \alpha^2 + \alpha^3 + \alpha^4 = 0$.

Your support is much appreciated! thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to solve an equation of the form $z^n=r cis(\theta)$ or $z^n=r e^{i\theta}$?

Comment: @Galc127 Hi! I'm new to this topic, hope you will guide me

Comment: By definition - if $z$ is a n-th root of unity, then $z^n=1$. Now, you should know that the solution of an equation of the form $z^n=re^{i \theta}$ is $\displaystyle z_k=\sqrt[n]{r}e^{\frac{i\theta+2\pi k}{n}}$. Good luck.

Comment: You're gooing to have a hard time proving $1+a^2+a^3+a^4=0$. You'll have better luck with $1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4=0$.

Comment: Are you still here, Nora?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one:
$$
\alpha = \cos(2\pi/5) + \mathbf i \sin (2\pi/5).
$$

Now that you know one, can you find a second one, and indeed, the rest of them?

Comment: It is a more interesting exercise, perhaps, to find exact values of the components.

Comment: Agreed. (Of course, $\cos(2\pi/5)$ *is* an exact value.) :) Also: this person seems to be wondering about complex numbers. His/her trig skills might be sufficient to determine the value of the trig functions in, say, surd form. I didn't want to presume that they were not.

Comment: (Yes, of course I mean radical expressions not involving trigonometric functions.) And yes, I agree, I meant not to suggest you'd misinterpreted the thrust of the problem, but just to suggest an interesting follow-up (in fact, one of my favorite precalculus problems) for the inclined reader.

Comment: Ah...nice point!

Comment: As vertices of a regular pentagon, the fifth roots of unity in the complex plane can be found by [straight-edge and compass construction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95579/construction-of-a-regular-pentagon).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $~a^5=1\iff a^5-1=0.~$ Now, what formula do you know for $a^n-1$ ? :-$)$

Answer (score 0):

If you can construct, which isn't that difficult with Pythagoras:

$$\cos(36°) = \frac{\sqrt{5} +1}{4}$$

You are done, since $2*36° = 72°$.