# Constructing a Regular Pentagon of a Desired Length

Tags: geometric-construction

I was working on a problem that needed to construct a regular pentagon of a desired length. I couldn’t solve it so checked the solution. The solution in the book was as follows:

1. Draw the line $AB$ of desired length of the pentagon.
2. Draw the perpendicular line $BC$ that is half the original line.
3. Draw hypotenuse $AC$, and extend it as length $BC$ to the point $D$.
4. Draw the circle with radius $BD$.
5. Now, using a ruler, drawing lines that intersect the circle and are the same length as $AB$ will construct a regular pentagon.

I don’t see why this works. And, then again, this solution uses measurements, how can it be done with just a compass and straightedge without measurements.

P.S. I feel bad for not managing to solve this question. How can I improve myself or is this an indicator that I don’t have a good future at math?

Comment: About your last sentence concerning your abilities in mathematics : Be confident : a lot of people who have specialized in mathematics weren't good at these issues which are very very specific.

Comment: [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95579/construction-of-a-regular-pentagon?rq=1)

On a side note, compass+straightedge construction is a well-studied theory. You need to start with the basic exercises first, if this is your first encounter.

Comment: About the "measurements" issue: Ruler-and-compass constructions (with the help of the [Compass Equivalence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_equivalence_theorem), if necessary) allow a length to be transferred from one place to another. And, of course, midpoints are constructible. So, there's no measuring *per se* in Steps 1 through 4. Now, although Step 5 mentions a ruler, it could/should have simply said something like: *Starting at any point on the circle in step 4, use a compass to mark-off a chain of five chords of length $AB$. This is the desired pentagon.*

Comment: @dezdichado This is not a duplicate as the regular pentagons constructed are quite different. The one you sent inscribes a regular pentagon on any given circle whereas my problem is with finding a circle which then inscribed with a pentagon, the length of the sides of the inscribed pentagon are a given length.

Comment: For the other two comments (ones except dezdichado’s) that are posted before this comment. Thank you your comments are precious and very useful.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck in understanding this? If we call the original length $2s$, do you see why (Step 2) $|\overline{BC}| = s$, and (Step 3) $|\overline{AC}| = s\sqrt{5}$ and $|\overline{AD}| = s(1+\sqrt{5})$? Step 4 would seem to be the trickiest one. The fact that $|\overline{BD}|$ gives the appropriate circumradius involves a little bit of trigonometry. (Seyed's answer side-steps this issue nicely.) What level of math are you supposed to be using here?

Comment: @Blue it was exactly step 4 where I was stuck. And yes while Seyed’s answer side-steps the issue, I still want to learn BD gives the appropriate circumradius. As for the level of math I can’t really tell it’s from a math puzzle book called 536 Puzzles and Curious Math Problems.

Comment: Well, then ... What level of math do you know? :)

Comment: I graduated high school this year and in my first college year. I’m majoring in EEE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OP has acknowledged in a comment, the tricky part is Step 4, so we ask

> Why is $\overline{BD}$ the desired circumradius?

We can answer this, somewhat unsatisfactorily, using the Law of Cosines on $\triangle ABD$. First, we'll note that the construction gives us these values for an assumed "given" length of $10s$ (to avoid some fractions): 
$$|\overline{AB}| = 10s \qquad |\overline{AD}| = 5s\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) \qquad \cos A = \frac{|\overline{AB}|}{|\overline{AC}|}=\frac{2s}{s\sqrt{5}}=\frac{2}{5}\sqrt{5}$$

So, by the Law of Cosines,
$$\begin{align}
|\overline{BD}|^2 &= (10s)^2 + \left(5s(1+\sqrt{5})\right)^2-2\cdot 10s\cdot  5s(1+\sqrt{5}) \cdot \frac{2}{5}\sqrt{5} \\[2pt]
&= 100s^2 + 25s^2 \left( 6 + 2 \sqrt{5} \right)- 40 s^2(\sqrt{5}+5) \\[6pt]
&= s^2 \left( 50 + 10 \sqrt{5} \right) \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
so that
$$|\overline{BD}| = s \sqrt{50 + 10\sqrt{5}} \tag{2}$$

which agrees with [MathWorld's](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pentagon.html) for the circumradius of a pentagon with side-length $10s$. $\square$

---

As I mentioned, this answer is unsatisfactory ... which may actually help assuage OP's self-doubts.

Sure, the calculation shows that the numbers work-out how they should, but it sheds no light on how anyone might have *expected* this result. (I didn't believe it worked until I did the trig verification (twice!), and I'm usually pretty good at perceiving stuff like this. *It's what I do.*)

More importantly, the calculation gives no indication about how anyone might naturally arrive at the given construction of a pentagon's circumradius. If *I* were tasked with constructing the length in $(2)$, that construction is not the route I would've taken first ... or even *ever*. (I probably would've done something far more complicated using the geometric mean construction.)

If, instead, I were asked to construct the pentagon with a given side, it would not have occurred to me to construct that complicated circumradius at all. Rather, I would have gone in the direction of @Seyed's construction, because I "know" the ratio of the diagonal to the side is the Golden Ratio, $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$, and I "know" how to construct a diagonal of the appropriate length. (That's the "obvious" stuff in Steps 1 through 3 of the construction in the question.)

In short: I find the construction in question quite non-intuitive. OP should not feel bad about not understanding the key relation. To be clear:

> This **IS NOT** an indicator that you don't have a good future in math.

(This may be an indicator, though, that whoever devised that surprising construction *does* (did?) have a good future in math!)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Have a nice day!

Comment: This may come out odd but after reading your answer for some reason I felt like reading the original question from the book and then it occurred to me that the question was not necessarily about how to construct the pentagon but rather how to construct the circumcircle. This might explain why it resorted to the solution used in the book. This creates the question that how do I find out the ratio of radius to pentagon side length of a circumcribed pentagon. Any advice?

Comment: Short answer: trig. :) For a longer answer, you should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: I’ll try it before asking here. If/when I ask, is there an easy way to notify you?

Comment: You can comment on this answer, or @-mention me in a comment on your question above. (@-mentioning on a new question does nothing, since screennames aren't unique. With a few "Blue"s here, the system wouldn't know which one to notify. There's less ambiguity among members of a comment conversation.)

Answer (score 3):

This is how to construct a regular pentagon using only a compass and straightedge without measurements.
[image]

Comment: can you tell how you found the point C? did you use the compass to draw an arc of radius AB to intersect the green arc?

Comment: @user500668, You have the $AN$ which is equal to $AD$ and $AC$, and you also have $AB$ which is the same as $BC$. To find the point $C$ you just need to make two arcs center at $A$ and $B$ and radius $AN$ and $1$.