# Can we construct $72^{\circ}$ with a compass and ruler?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, galois-theory, geometric-construction

I wanted to know  if it is possible to construct a $72^{\circ}$ angle via a ruler and compass? I know some numbers cannot be constructed using a ruler and compass, due to Galois Theory, but I don't exactly know how to check if a number falls in that category or not. Any resources would be appreciated as well!

Comment: Since you can construct a regular pentagon (and its exterior angle is what you need), why not? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon#Construction_of_a_regular_pentagon

Comment: To answer your broader question, think about what regular polygons are constructible, and what angles are derivable from them. Constructible polygons are intimately related to Fermat primes,

Comment: $72^o=360^o/5$, See the construction of the pentagon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Construction of a regular pentagon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95579/construction-of-a-regular-pentagon)

Comment: You can calculate $\cos72^{\circ}$, and then you can use Galois Theory to show that number is constructible, then you can use that construction to get a $72^{\circ}$ angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't need Galois theory. We have $\cos(72^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt5-1}4$, so we can construct $72^\circ$ using the following steps:

1. Draw a line of length $\sqrt5$. (It is well-known that [you can construct $\sqrt a$ from $a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705/compass-and-straightedge-construction-of-the-square-root-of-a-given-line))
2. Subtract $1$.
3. Divide by $4$. (Repeatedly bisecting; this creates $\cos(72^\circ)$)
4. Draw a right triangle with hypotenuse $1$ and adjacent $\cos(72^\circ)$. (In detail: Draw a perpendicular line from the line segment of length $\cos(72^\circ)$ drawn above, and intersect with a circle of length $1$.)
5. The angle the two lines above create is $72^\circ$.

Comment: Thankyou so much!